# Month over Month change in table without including any other column

Tags: dax

I'm trying to show the MoM for each salesperson by region. Right Now i have managed to create a MoM measure however it return 0 when I remove column on the percentage of sales the salesperson has done

[image]

This is my month over month measure code

```
MoM% = 
VAR __PREV_MONTH = CALCULATE(SUM('Sales share'[Sales]), DATEADD('Date'[Date], -1, MONTH))
RETURN
    DIVIDE(SUM('Sales share'[Sales]) - __PREV_MONTH, __PREV_MONTH)
```

This is the code I used to get the sales percentage

```
% Sales = 

DIVIDE(
    SUM('Sales share'[Sales]),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Sales share'[Sales]),
        ALLSELECTED('Sales share'[Name])
    )
)
```

Comment: `MoM%` is showing 0 in your screen grab above with `% Sales` - is your `MoM%` working? Which table/columns have used in your Matrix visual columns?

Comment: Yes it works now . I added a date table and put a relationship